# how to produce a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

How can I produce a matrix in the form below in r? I can produce a matrix with all 0 in there, but I am not sure how to write the for loops to fill in the rest of it.

```
a <-10
m<-matrix(0,a,a)
```

[image]

The rest part of the matrix are all 0.

Comment: What have you tried and where you got stuck? There's clear pattern in the matrix and you should be able to do it with 2 for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bit harder than expected :), but you could do like this:

```
createMatrix <- function(n){
  firstCol <- rep(0, n + 2)
  lastCol <- rep(0, n + 2)
  firstCol[c((n + 2), n + 1)] <- c(1 - 1/(n + 2), 1/(n + 1))
  lastCol[c((n + 2), n + 1)] <- c(1/(n + 2), 1 - 1/(n + 1))
  mat1 <- diag(x = 1/(n:1), n, n)[n:1, ]
  mat2 <- diag(x = (1 - 1/(1:n)), n, n)
  mat1[mat1 == 0] <- mat2[mat1 == 0]
  unname(cbind(firstCol, rbind(mat1, rep(0, n), rep(0, n)), lastCol))
}

> createMatrix(4)
          [,1] [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.0000000 0.00 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.00 0.0000000
[2,] 0.0000000 0.00 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.00 0.0000000
[3,] 0.0000000 0.00 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.00 0.0000000
[4,] 0.0000000 0.25 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.75 0.0000000
[5,] 0.2000000 0.00 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00 0.8000000
[6,] 0.8333333 0.00 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00 0.1666667
```

Comment: Alright there is a misunderstanding here, maybe I should not use n to define the number of rows and columns again. The n in the picture is not equal to what I wrote in the code, please just ignore it. The n will change with the number of rows, like n=1 in the first row, n=2 in the second row.....

Comment: not a matter of understanding but  specification ;) What would be your idea to change the code accordingly?

Comment: I think maybe should use for loop in the code? Because the value of n is changing along the rows

Comment: Well I think the result is still not right. For example, the value of (1,2) should be 0 and (1,5) should be 1, (2,4) should be 0.5.

Comment: thanks for accepting, an upvote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For filling one diagonal you can use :

```
 diag(m) <- "1-1/n"
```

For the other diagonal you can use a loop(as i cannot figure out the same for other diagonal).